# How do I properly use the less than and greater than sign in Python

Tags: python

So I have the following function in my script:

```
def age():
    global age
    age = raw_input("Age: ")

    if age == 14:
        sleep(1)
        print ("LOL, same")
    
    elif age < 18:
        sleep(1)
        print ("This test is made for contestants older than ten")
        introduction()  
        
    elif age > 18:
        sleep(1)
        print ("Geez grandpa, you sure are old")
```

When I run this, it registers every age I type as above 18 like so:

> Could you tell me your age?
>
> Age: 4
>
> Geez grandpa, you sure are old

Why does it do this?

Comment: Change `age = raw_input("Age: ")` to `age = int(raw_input("Age: "))`. The result of `raw_input` is a string, which Python 2.7 will allow you to compare with an `int`

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer. You'll have to convert it first if you want to compare that with other integers. See the duplicate.

Comment: You should use Python 3; it won’t fail silently on these types of errors.

Answer (score 3):

As `raw_input` returns the user input as a string type, you should cast it into int.

Change this :

```
age = raw_input("Age: ")
```

To:

```
age = int(raw_input("Age: "))
```

Comment: Sir, I need to talk with you, Can we chat ?

Comment: Yes, No problem @SurajJain

Comment: Can you create chat ?

Answer (score 0):

your raw_input is taken as string

```
age = raw_input("Age: ")
```

so you need to convert it into a integer value if you want to compare it against numbers..

```
age = int(raw_input("Age: "))
```